# UWP WebView not showing Google Maps markers

Tags: xamarin, webview, uwp

We are facing an issue related to the UWP WebView inside a Xamarin Forms application. Until lately, Google Maps markers were shown correctly on the native UWP WebView, but suddenly, they are not shown any more. Anyone else has run across this issue and has been able to solve it?

P.D: We are using Xamarin Forms version 5.0.0.2012, and application target platform version is 10.0.18362.0.

We have tried with a native UWP project, and the same result.

Comment: Could you please share the code that you used in UWP project for test?

Comment: It would be a bit tricky to share the code as it is about a project with thousands of lines. The fact is the webview loads an html coupled with the google maps javascript api, in order to show the map and the markers. It has been working like a charm for years, but out of nowhere it does not show the markers any longer.

Comment: Same issue here, was working in the past, at some point no more. Still working for android and attempted to upgrade to Maui (Wuin UI3) it works there as well. Have no solution though.

Answer (score 0):

We got this issue solved by upgrading google maps javascript api in the web project that was shown in the webview. We were still using an older version.

we basically changed an added script tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.33...
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.51...
```